# Empty IFrame since Firefox 62

Tags: javascript, firefox, webforms

I have a curious bug with my Iframe since Firefox 62 release.

I'm using Iframe to show error Messages or Information to the user in my Webforms application but now every Iframe is empty. The Iframe shows up but there is no content.

This is how I built them:

```
Public Sub ShowHint_JS(ByVal pv_strMessage As String, ByVal pv_strEvent As String)

        Dim objMessage As New CMessage
        Dim objUtilities As New CCommonFunctions(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))

        AddJavaScript("$('form').append('" & objMessage.buildMessage(objUtilities.GetStruktur() & "common/Message.aspx", pv_strMessage, 0, 0, 0, 0, pv_strEvent, "") & "');", "HW_JS")
End Sub

Public Sub AddJavaScript(ByVal pv_strJavaScript As String, ByVal pv_strBlockName As String)

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), pv_strBlockName, "$(document).ready(function(){" & pv_strJavaScript & "});", True)
End Sub
```

// In my CMessage Class:

```
public string buildMessage(string pv_strMessage, string pv_strEvent)
        {
            Session["MESSAGEEVENT"] = pv_strEvent;

            return convertHtmlControlToString(buildMessageIFrame("common/Message.aspx", 80, 200, 400, 260, pv_strMessage));
        }

private HtmlGenericControl buildMessageIFrame(string pv_strURL, int pv_intTop, int pv_intLeft, int pv_intWidth, 
                                                        int pv_intHeight, string pv_strMessage)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl objIframe = new HtmlGenericControl("iframe");

            if (!pv_strURL.Contains("?"))
            {
                pv_strURL += "?";
            }
            else
            {
                if(!pv_strURL.EndsWith("&"))
                {
                    pv_strURL += "&";
                }
            }

            Session["DIVCount"] = (m_objObjHandl.NZ_Int(Session["DIVCount"], 0) + 1);
            Session["Message_ifrm" + m_objObjHandl.NZ_Str(Session["DIVCount"], "")] = pv_strMessage;

            objIframe.ID = "ifrm" + Session["DIVCount"].ToString();
            objIframe.Attributes.Add("class", "iFrameHint invisible");
            objIframe.Attributes.Add("frameborder", "0");
            objIframe.Attributes.Add("scrolling", "no");
            objIframe.Attributes.Add("src", pv_strURL + "height=" + pv_intHeight.ToString() + "&iframe=" + objIframe.ID.ToString());
            objIframe.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("top", pv_intTop.ToString() + "px");
            objIframe.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("left", pv_intLeft.ToString() + "px");
            objIframe.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("width", pv_intWidth.ToString() + "px");
            objIframe.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("height", pv_intHeight.ToString() + "px");

            return objIframe;
        }
```

Here is my Message.aspx which should be shown in the iFrame

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/common/MasterMessage.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cntHead" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function buildWindow(pv_strUrl) {
            var arrUrl = pv_strUrl.split('#');

            if (arrUrl.length = 1) {
                createWindow(arrUrl[0]);
            }

            if (arrUrl.length = 2) {
                createWindow(arrUrl[0], arrUrl[1]);
            }

            if (arrUrl.length = 3) {
                createWindow(arrUrl[0], arrUrl[1], arrUrl[2]);
            }

            if (arrUrl.length > 3) {
                createWindow(arrUrl[0], arrUrl[1], arrUrl[2], arrUrl[3]);
            }
        }

        function redirectParent(pv_strAddress) {
            var objParent = parent.document;

            objParent.location.href = pv_strAddress;
        }
    </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cntMessage" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody">
    <table class="tblMessage">
        <tr class="tdHintHeader">
            <td style="width: 97%;">
                Message</td>
            <td id="tdClose">
                <img alt="Close" src="../img/cross.gif" class="FunctionImg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="OuterTable">
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; background-color: #D0E0FF;" class="hint top center">
                <div id="divContent" class="divMessageContent"><span>
                    <%Response.Write.NZ_Str(Session("MESSAGE_" & NZ_Str(Request.QueryString("iframe")))).Replace(vbCrLf, "<br />").Replace(vbNewLine, "<br />").Replace(vbCr, "<br />"))%>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="OuterTable">
            <td class="center" colspan="2" style="height: 30px;">
                <input type="button" value="OK" class="button" style="width: 100px;" onclick="<%= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString("event")) %>;closeMe();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Solution:

Changed the property from my CSS-Class for the div with my content from

> overflow: auto;

to

> overflow: visible;

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: no console errors

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the absence of **Content-Security-Policy**.

To avoid this, try to add the following to your **web.config** file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self';"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Hope you'll find this useful.

Comment: Thanks but I solved the problem. One of my <div> had a css class with overflow: auto; I switched it to overflow: visible.